# Magento2 - Which namespaces to be used inside a class

Tags: magento2, design-patterns

This might be a novice question, but as when a developer starts to learn Magento2,how do i figure out which all namespaces must be used inside a Model,Block,Plugin or matter of fact any custom class which has been created in Magento2.

In Magento1.x.x , following scenario used to occur.

- Block/Model/Helper - Either it can be extended from default skeleton 
  class or any core block class file.
- controllers - Had to extend a       frontcontroller class, or include
  another class file and extend it.
  So this was fairly straightforward.

So is the case with Magento2, i have to first search for all possible dependencies for my class, include those namespace, di it and then start coding?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that no need to analyze all possible dependencies.

You can add dependencies in natural way, when you need call some method from some class - you add class as dependency.